# How to get certificate of https bindings in c#?

Tags: c#, iis, binding, certificate, iis-7.5

I try to get some certificate in the iis - version 7.5.
How to get certificate of "https" binding in c#?

Comment: Hi, i try to find the certificate of some binding of https in the iis - using c#.
i don`t find any place in the internet with that explanation.
anybody here know how can i do it?
Thanks!

Comment: tutorials on how to create self-signed SSL certificate and use in IIS: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis ,  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates

Comment: I need to do it in c# code, it doesn`t help me.
Thanks on the answer anyway